Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got undefined In Next.Js
I have been moving files around in my Next.js 14.2.20 application to migrate to FSD and clean architecture. Imports worked before, and after having finished the migration, ALL my pages trigger a server error at runtime and during build.
Typescript throws no error.
During build
Error logs look something like this:
// same logs for other pages

Error occurred prerendering page "/vocabulaire/username". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
    at nM (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61599)
    at nM (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61546)
    at nN (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64546)
    at nB (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:67538)
    at nM (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:58560)
    at nN (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64546)
    at nB (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:67538)
    at nD (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:66680)
    at nN (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64853)
    at nB (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:67538)
 ✓ Generating static pages (46/46)

During dev at runtime
⨯ Internal error: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    at aw (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46775)
    at aw (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46505)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at aj (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:53793)
    at /Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:42336
    at aw (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:42822)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at aj (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:53793)
    at aC (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:52874)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:50095)
    at aj (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:53793)
    at /Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:42336
    at aw (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:42822)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at aj (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:53793)
    at aC (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:52874)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:50095)
    at aj (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:53793)
    at aC (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:52874)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:50095)
    at aj (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:53793)
    at aC (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:52874)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:50095)
    at ac (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11400)
    at aw (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:14707)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at ab (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
    at /Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
    at aw (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at aj (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:53793)
    at aC (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:52874)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:50095)
    at aw (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:42922)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at ac (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11400)
    at aw (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:14707)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at ab (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
    at /Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
    at aw (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at aw (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:45321)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at aw (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:45321)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at aw (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:45321)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at aw (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:45321)
    at a_ (/Users/XXX/Developer/repos/XXX/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
digest: "833637954"

My question
How am I supposed to debug something with such poor logs ? I can't even think where to start, as it is a big application and checking git diff is impossible because code migration targeted hundreds of files per commit.

update: this might be because of webpack alias resolution, but whatever alias declaration I add to the webpack configuration in next.config.mjs, it does not work.
